# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 405

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a Web Socket with Spring and SockJs, I have to expose the Socket also for a "WebSocket" standard.

I have my handler:

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(mySocketHandler(), "/mySocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
```

When I create the websocket via browser, with this:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8443/myApp/mySocket')
```

I have the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8443/myApp/mySocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 405
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: So your server supports encrypted connections? How did you configure that?

Comment: sure it supports them. My app is served in https and uses already sockets with sockjs.

Comment: _"uses already sockets with sockjs"_ - which can use fallback options. Maybe websockets are not yet configured to be used with SSL/TLS.

Comment: I don't understand. The application can normally connect to web sockets using sockjs; I'm trying to add a normal WebSocket but I have that error...

Comment: _"The application can normally connect to web sockets using sockjs"_ That was my point: Maybe it does not(!) connect via websockets but uses a fallback option, because websockets don't work on your server. SockJS can(!) use websockets.

Comment: I have found the solution, it's not a SSL problem. Thanks in any case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution.

This error occoured because in the @Configuration component the annotation @EnableWebSocket was missing.

After adding @EnableWebSocket, the connection was correctly established.